# Telegram: how to properly make an SSL certificate for a Webhook on shared hosting?

Tags: php, ssl, ssl-certificate, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm having problems configuring Webhook for Telegram Bot API.

I have shared hosting and used [this](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/ssl/how-to-install-free-ssl-from-lets-encypt-on-shared-hosting) tutorial to set up a free letsencrypt certificate. I even installed it on a website:

[image]

And it appears to be working:

[image]

However, the Telegram bot bound to this webhook does not reply to messages, in fact -- it's not even triggering the webhook.
I'm using [telegram-site-helper](https://github.com/Surzhikov/Telegram-Site-Helper-2.0). Somehow, if I put `sendMessage(token, "xxxxxxx", "hi")` at top of my webhook.php where `xxxxxxx` is my Telegram ID (got it via [@get_id_bot](https://telegram.me/get_id_bot)) my bot would send me a message without any problems.

I used [getWebhookInfo](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getwebhookinfo) to check the status of my webhook, here's what it returns:

`{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://website.url/path/to/webhook.php","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":19,"last_error_date":1488716929,"last_error_message":"SSL error {336134278, error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed}","max_connections":40}}`

Comment: There must be a problem with your certificate, try uploading it while sending setwebhook, I guess telegram-site-helper has a field to upload the certification file. And as far as I know most of shared hosting don't allow you to use ssl without buying a dedicated ip address. That might cause some errors although you have a green ssl on chrome (just saying)

Comment: @AliPadida Yes, the problem is with the certificate. I somehow need to provide a full certificate chain on shared hosting. Any ideas?

Comment: Analyze your ssl with this website:
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html
see if there are any errors? also you can try connecting your domain to cloudflare, it has a free ssl. 

Also, I'm thinking you've given a wrong callback url for setwebhook, in error message, it says: https://website.url/path/to/webhook.php . Did you change it to hide your url? or that's the exact message you receive?